# Which is correct: "The facts are known by us" or "The facts are known to us"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is correct?

> The facts are known by us

or

> The facts are known to us

I think *by* is correct but my friends persist that it's *to*.

Answer (score 8):

Both are grammatically correct. However *known to* is idiomatic and included in Oxford Dictionaries' examples:

> 1. Recognized, familiar, or within the scope of knowledge:
>      *plants little known to western science*
>
> [known, ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/known)

*Known by* in a passive construction such as that, although not incorrect, is definitely awkward. The passive voice is used when the agent is immaterial and omissible: "The facts are known." If the facts are known by us, then the passive-voice construction is  unnecessary: "We know the facts." Subverting the use of the passive voice by tacking "by us" on the end is what makes it awkward.

*Known to* is an idiomatic set phrase and not a passive construction.

Comment: Active: *I know John*. Passive: *John is known to me*. Is that not the case? In order for it to be construed as passive, would you have to say: *John is known by me* I realise that it conveys a different nuance depending on whether one uses *to* or *by*.

Comment: I'm struggling with identifying _known_'s position along the verb-adjective continuum in 'John is known to me'. By comparing with say 'unknown to science' and 'familiar to me', I think I've got to put it at the 'adjective' end and analyse the to-phrase as a prepositional-phrase complement of the adjective. So 'known' in 'known to ...' isn't [necessarily] the same part of speech as in 'known by'. Compare the _broken_'s in 'The window was broken by the stone' and 'The window was broken, we sadly observed'.

Comment: I'm not sure  what you're asking, @WS2, as you seem to be contradicting yourself. As Andrew says, _known to_ is not a passive: I would describe it as using the adjective _known_ (derived from a past participle) which subcategorises for an optional knower with _to_.